# How to sample N points between 0 and R if they are exponentially distributed?

Tags: math, distribution, probability-density

The density of my points x ∈ [0,R] is exponential: ρ(x)~e^x
How can I sample N points from there?

Comment: This is more of a statistics question than a programming question.  You want to take the uniform distribution from a random function (drand48), and transform that uniform distribution into an exponential distribution.

Comment: A couple of comments that you may think are nit-picking but that make a huge difference in what the answer is: 1) What's commonly called the exponential distribution has density `exp(-lambda * x) / lambda`, where `lambda > 0`. That minus sign is really important! 2) The range of the exponential distribution is `[0,\infty]`, if you have an upper bound of `R` you have a truncated exponential which alters the method of generating. 3) If you meant what you said and the density is proportional to `exp(x)`, you'll have to scale it to get an area of 1.  So what is it you really want here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking your request at face value, if you want a density function that grows exponentially for x ∈ [0,R] the cumulative distribution function turns out to be `(exp(x) - 1) / (exp(R) - 1)`.  To generate this via inversion, set the CDF equal to a `Uniform(0,1)` and solve for `x`.  The inversion turns out to be:

```
ln(1 + (exp(R) - 1) * U)
```

where U represents a call to the Uniform(0,1) PRNG.

If what you actually want is a truncated form of what most probability folks know as the exponential distribution, we need to determine an upper bound for the random number corresponding to your truncation point `R`.  In that case, the inversion is:

```
-ln(1 - [1 - exp(-lambda * R)] * U) / lambda
```

As before, U represents a call to the Uniform(0,1) PRNG.  This will generate exponentials at rate `lambda`, truncated at a max of `R`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [inverse sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling): you generate uniform distributed values and map them to the output of the cdf of your distribution.

Comment: To spell it out for this case: generate a uniformly distributed value in 0-1 and take its logarithm.

Comment: @Joni That won't quite do it. If the density is growing exponentially you'll need to scale the uniform to keep it in the range [0,R].  If it's exponentially decaying, you'll need the negative of the logarithm and additional scaling to keep it in the specified range.